# How to open new URL in the same tab with Selenium, but with some way with editing the URL?

Tags: java, selenium, url, intellij-idea

I want to open a new URL in the same tab in Selenium, but I need to somehow edit the URL. What working options are there? I am thinking about navigating by keys, but the problem is that the URL can't be inspected.

Comment: Did this work for you ?
`String newURL=https://somedomain.com/path?query=1
driver.get(newURL);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To open and edit the url on the same tab:

1) First you need to get the current page url, to do so:

**getCurrentUrl command :**

> Usage : Used to get the URL of the currently opened web page in the
>   browser.
>
> Syntax : driver.getCurrentUrl();
>
> Return type : String (Returns the URL of current web page)

**Example :**

```
String currentURL  = driver.getCurrentUrl();
System.out.println(currentURL);
```

2) Now editing url:
   With the above url, now you can change whatever to want to:
   example:

```
String currentURL  = driver.getCurrentUrl();
//Let assume CurrentUrl = {something}/product/id1/
String editURL = currentURL.replace("id1", "id2")
                     OR
String editURL = currentURL + "/something/";
```

3) Opening edited url on the same tab.

```
driver.get(editURL);
       OR
driver.navigate().to(editURL);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a Selenium method called `getCurrentUrl`. Use it like so,

```
String currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
String newURL = currentURL + "yourEdit";
```